# Python readlines() 3.X to 2.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a script originally written for python 3.5+. I am needing to convert it to 2.6.2.
In the script I utilize `readlines()` which I believe behaves differently between the two versions.
Specifically I am using the `readlines()` to retrieve data from a txt file that is separated by line breaks.

Here is a snippit:

```
t=open(supportID+"stmp.txt","r")
timeIn=(t.readlines())
a=(str(timeIn))
supportID=(t.readlines())
b=(str(supportID))
branch=(t.readlines())
c=(str(branch))
clientID=(t.readlines())
d=(str(clientID))
problem=(t.readlines())
e=(str(problem))
solution=(t.readlines())
f=(str(solution))
timeOut=(t.readlines())
g=(str(timeOut))
```

In my script for 3.x I had a '1' in each of the `readlines()` and it performed as needed, however with 2.x this does not work. I have tried entering values 1-7 and blank as seen above.

With some research I discovered that some 2.x users use `with open(filename)`
Is this the preferred method or is there a way to alter my original to make it work?

EDIT:
So im going to use this format

```
with open(supportID+"stmp.txt") as t:
    for line in t:
        print(line)
```

I plugged this in and it works, printing each line as a line in my shell. Now I will want to use this to assign each line to a variable.

EDIT 2:
This is currently working for my environment but is not best practice for this function. Reads in each line and assigns each line to a variable.

```
t=open(supportID+"stmp.txt","r")
lines = t.readlines()
t.close()
a=lines[0]
b=lines[1]
c=lines[2]
...
```

Comment: This would not work as you say in Python 3, it works the same as Python 2 here. The `with` statement is used in both Python 2 and 3, btw. I'm going to guess in your Python 3 script you were using `readline` instead of `readlines`

Comment: using `x=readlines(1)` worked to read through a tmp file in 3x line by line in my environment. Youre saying `with open(x)` would be the preffered method in 3.x and 2.x?

Comment: You aren't use `realines(1)`, and you shouldn't be, that is an upper bound in *bytes* not *lines*. You should be using `readline`. And yes, you should always use a context manager (the with statement) to open files.

Comment: *originally* I had `readlines(1)`. But If you could explain why that is bytes and not lines I would appreciate it. I have just stumbled upon this as an option in 2x and 3x                 `with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       print(line)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to explain. The "why" is answered "because that's what the language designers decided the argument should mean". You should check the docs.

Comment: Yes, that is the idiomatic way of reading a file line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **read in each line from the file and assign to a variable** I used this method for python 2.6.2

```
t=open(supportID+"stmp.txt","r")
lines = t.readlines()
t.close()
a=lines[0]
b=lines[1]
c=lines[2]
...
```

Comment: Unless you actually *need* the list `lines`, there's no real reason to use `readlines`. `a = t.readline()`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

try this code: (I assume it will work with python version >= 2.6)

```
with open('lines.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       print(line.strip())
```

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga. I dont know.. 'Newb 4 You BB' should explain better what he tries to do.

Comment: @balderman what is going on in my script is im taking using input that is stored in a file separated by line breaks. I then have this section attempting to grab each line as a separate piece of information to input into another file.